# Where are the Azure trace logs on a local box when UseDevelopmentStorage=true

Tags: azure, logging, trace, diagnostics

I am running a Windows Azure Project in an emulator on a local box and have set the flag UseDevelopmentStorage=true for tracing. However, I cannot figure out where the traces/logs go, if they get written at all. I appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Archil

Comment: From where in your code do you write traces? Is it a WebRole or a WorkerRole?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://blog.bareweb.eu/2011/01/beginning-azure-diagnostics/ you should have a WADLogsTable showing up in your Table storage node. You need to make sure that Diagnostics are enabled.

[image: Diagnostics enabled]

And that you enable transfers

```
public override bool OnStart()
{
DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration diagnosticMonitorConfiguration = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();
diagnosticMonitorConfiguration.Logs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0);
CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
DiagnosticMonitor diagnosticMonitor = DiagnosticMonitor.Start(cloudStorageAccount, diagnosticMonitorConfiguration);
return base.OnStart();
}
```

Comment: I have all those settings configured as shown above. In your link I read:

"Your vanilla application has part of the setup that you require done for you, but not the entire amount. The project properties of your role provides a way to configure the diagnostics for you, but using this approach the data will never be transferred to Cloud Storage, as it is never configured to schedule a transfer for you. This means the logs will be written locally to each role..."

So where are the logs written locally? I want to look at them locally. I don't want them transferred to a central location yet.

Comment: Your SQL Database (sqlexpress by default).

Comment: The transfer means to table storage (which in your case is development storage) as Richard says - SqlExpress. If you open up the compute emulator you can also see the logs scroll by. And to be clear - the above article is not mine, I just have used his examples for my own Azure tinkering.

Comment: Yep, I do see them now scroll by in the compute emulator window. However I do not see any errors in the DevelopmentStorageDB. That could be because I played with the .config file and disabled tracing by accident. Anyway thanks for you help. And yes, I only referred to the link as pasted by you and realize that the article is not yours.

Comment: The missing bit is most likely that this code isn't in your project `public override bool OnStart()
{
DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration diagnosticMonitorConfiguration = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();
diagnosticMonitorConfiguration.Logs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0);
CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
DiagnosticMonitor diagnosticMonitor = DiagnosticMonitor.Start(cloudStorageAccount, diagnosticMonitorConfiguration);
return base.OnStart();
}`

Answer (score 0):

In the windows system tray click on a a Windows Azure blue icon and pick Show Compute Emulator UI. In the window that opens up find you role instance on the left and click on it. You will see the traces scroll by.